# Parse cloud code javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

what is wrong with this code ?
I'm new to javascript, never did it. I copied the code to jsfiddle as suggested by many programmers, and copied it again to my main.js file . I run 'parse deploy' in my terminal , which fails to deploy giving an error 'Unexpected Token ILLEGAL'
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
Parse.Cloud.define(‘incNumOfFollowers’, function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query(“_User”);
query.equalTo(“objectId”, request.params.userId);
query.find({
success: function(user) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  user.increment(“xnumberOfFollowers”);
  user.save().then(function(user) {
    response.success(user);
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error)
  });
},
error: function() {
  response.error(“user not found”);
}
});
});
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code clearly uses single and double quotation marks that are not allowed in Javascript. Replace `‘` with `'` and replace `“` with `"` in your code